# How to use .split so that it removes a certain group of words?

Tags: java, android

I am inputting this through an EditText:

"I need to go to the dentist 2 weeks later."

Let's call that string "value".

I want value.split to do such a thing that the whole sentence is split into groups of strings.

Such as

"i need to" ---> need

"go to the dentist" ---> task

"2 weeks later." ---> time

Is this possible via .split? If it is not, how can I execute this code?

Comment: What are the rules for this split? First three words are always the need? Next four always the task? Last three always the time?

Comment: Split operates on a string using a regular expression as a delimiter. It is not a language parser.

Comment: This problem is much bigger than how do I split strings.  As Ken says, unless you have 100% strict rules on how many words make each phrase of the sentence, you cannot just do this with split.  You need to understand the rules used, the grammar used and the semantics of the sentence before you can begin to parse it.  You are attempting to solve one of the biggest problems in computing.

Comment: There is no specific rule as to how many words the need will be. It doesn't seem THAT hard to accomplish through writing a function though..

Comment: Such function will be very specific - not general.
You could provide user with interface to input task and time separetly.

Comment: I am not trying to write a grammar-understanding AI, I just need this action done then I can do the others by changing the code I already have.

Answer (score 2):

`split` is able to split into the individual words, so your example sentence would become 10 words: "I", "need", "to" etc.  But it sounds like you need some artificial intelligence to be involved, to work out the meaning of the words.  That's not possible with `split` and is a very hard problem.